# Error with a Simple vertex shader

Tags: opengl, vertex-shader

I'm having a problem following this tutorial [The First Triangle](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-2-the-first-triangle/). I actually managed to get the First part working, but when it comes to the vertex shader it doesn't work.

Here is my Vertex Shader Code:

```
#version 330 core

// Input vertex data, different for all executions of this shader.
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;

void main(){
gl_Position.xyz = vertexPosition_modelspace;
gl_Position.w = 1.0;
}
```

It's just a copy of the Tutorial, but it gives me this error: must write to gl_Position.`

Just don't know what to do now.

EDIT: I'm using a GeForce 9500GT with 319.32 Drivers

EDIT2: I actually got the same thing in an older version, but it has the same error.
Here is the code:

```
#version 120
// Input vertex data, different for all executions of this shader.
attribute vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;

void main(){

gl_Position = vec4(vertexPosition_modelspace, 1.0);

}
```

EDIT3: I'm using SFML as my default library.

Comment: Please stop posting error code numbers as though they had any real meaning. Also, what hardware are you compiling this on?

Comment: Using a 9500GT with Ubuntu Linux

Comment: Can you go with a dead simple vertex shader and see if it works? (#version 120 as it is, inside main():
gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex; )

Comment: There must be something else wrong here. Can you post the whole source code? Are you sure the nvidia driver is correctly installed and configured? Can you check with `glxinfo`?

Comment: I'm sorry guys, I think the problem is in my changes to make that code work with SFML since it actually worked using the code provided by the tutorial. Now I'm just looking for the shader use in SFML. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I came to realize that what I were doing was kind of wrong thanks to you that helped me.
If anyone has this kind of problem the best option is to try the libraries (SFML) native functions. 
That's what I'm doing now using [this tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/graphics-shader.php).

Answer (score -3):

if your shader files have more than one newline [0D0A] at a time in succession, or if they consist of only 0D or 0A, you will have a bad day.

GOOD ->

```
#version 330 core
in vec3 ourColor;
out vec4 color;
void main()
{
    color = vec4(ourColor, 1.0f);
}
```

BAD ->

```
#version 330 core

in vec3 ourColor;

out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    color = vec4(ourColor, 1.0f);
}
```

at least that is what worked for me...

Comment: That's really not backed by the spec. Maybe your shader loading code is just broken.

Comment: i'll have to correct myself here.  providing the full path to the shader files as arguments to the Shader class brought everything up to speed.  that is something i did without realizing it after tweaking newlines (which is, as you say, completely irrelevant).  that is all.